# Función contar_primos

Tags: python, funciones, lista

El enunciado que tengo es el siguiente:

"Realice una función de nombre contar_primos() que reciba como argumento una lista de números enteros y devuelva la cantidad de números primos que hay en la lista".

El problema es que al momento de ejecutarlo me pone:

> 2
>   None
>   2
>   None

y en su lugar debería leerse:

> 2
>   0

Este es el programa que tengo hasta el momento. Cualquier modificación es bienvenida:

```
#FUNCIONES

def es_primo(x):
  if x<2:
    return False
  for i in range(2,x):
    if (x%i)==0:
      return False
  return True


def contar_primos(L):
  c=0
  for i in range(len(L)):
    if es_primo(i)== True:
      c+=1
      print i     
      break


#PROGRAMA PPAL

L=[1,2,3]    
print contar_primos(L)   
L=[1,4,4,6]       
print contar_primos(L)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos problemas básicamente:

- Se imprime `None` porque toda función retorna `None` en Python si no se le especifica otra cosa. Si quieres que la función retorne el número de primos debes retornar tu variable `c` y no imprimir nada en la propia función.
- Por otro lado, en tu función `contar_primos` no recorres la lista de primos sino un rango desde 0 hasta el número de elementos de la lista, por lo que el resultado no será correcto, debes usar `for i in L:`.

Con esto, tu función debe quedar así:

```
def contar_primos(L):
    c=0
    for n in L:
        if es_primo(n):
            c+=1
    return c
```

Como usas Python 2.x usa `xrange` en lugar de `range` que es más eficiente (es un 'sequence object', similar a un generador, al igual que `range` en Python 3). En Python 2.x `range` retorna una lista, lo cual es ineficiente, sobretodo cuando en la mayoría de los casos no completas el `for`.

Aparte de esto, la función  `es_primo` es muy optimizable :

- No es necesario calcular el módulo de todos los números, basta con hacerlo solo con los impares y el 2. Ten en cuenta que los posibles factores van a ser primos y no hay primos pares (menos el 2).
- Tampoco es necesario comprobar desde 2 hasta `x`, basta con hacerlo hasta la raiz cuadrada de `x`. Esto es así porque siempre hay, al menos, un factor que es menor o igual a la raiz cuadrada. Si encontramos un divisor ya sabemos que es compuesto.

El código quedaria así:

```
#FUNCIONES

def es_primo(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True

    if x < 2 or not x % 2:
        return False

    for i in xrange(3, int(x**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if not x % i:
            return False

    return True


def contar_primos(L):
    c=0
    for n in L:
        if es_primo(n):
            c+=1
    return c


#PROGRAMA PPAL
L=[1,2,3]    
print contar_primos(L)   
L=[1,4,4,6]       
print contar_primos(L)
```

Se pueden añadir otras mejoras como:

- Usar `any` junto a un generador en `es_primo` para el `for`.
- Usar un generador por compresión y `sum` para `contar_primos`.

En este caso quedaría así:

```
#FUNCIONES

def es_primo(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True

    if x < 2 or not x % 2:
        return False

    return not any(x % i == 0 for i in xrange(3, int(x**0.5) + 1, 2))


def contar_primos(L):
    return sum(es_primo(n) for n in L)


#PROGRAMA PPAL
L=[1,2,3]    
print contar_primos(L)   
L=[1,4,4,6]       
print contar_primos(L)
```

Para ambos casos la salida es:

> 2
>   0

**Nota:** elevar un número a 0.5 equivale a obtener su raiz cuadrada.